# jQuery menu active link

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, hyperlink, anchor

I am trying to make a jquery menu that when I click on one of the links (without reloading the page), it changes its class to "active" and removes this class when I click on another link.

here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buttons").children().("a").click(function() {
    $(".buttons").children().toggleClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  });
});
</script>


  <ul class="buttons">
    <li><a class="button" href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#">Link4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Can someone tell me why my code is not working and how to fix it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original code failed because this syntax is invalid:

```
.children().("a")
```

The rest of the code also had some fundamental flaws. Try this instead:

```
$(function () {
  $('.buttons a').click(function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    var $li = $target.parent();
    $li.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

In this correction, the class `selected` is applied to an `<li>`—not an `<a>`—to give you better flexibility while writing CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I would change:

```
$(".buttons").children().toggleClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

to

```
$("this").addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buttons a").click(function() {
    $(".buttons a").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected"); 
  });
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that this may produce erratic results due to race conditions where you can't be sure addClass will be fired after RemoveClass.

Comment: @Jud You are correct, however I have used this in production code and never had it clash with itself.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but doesn't JavaScript's single threaded nature mean that it will run each line one at a time, invoking any extra code (like jQuery's internal methods) before moving onto the next line to execute?

Comment: I wouldn't bet too much on it, but I implemented that exact function with varying results. But, if it works in this scenario, why fix it?

Comment: your solution works, but unfortunately it doesn't give the flexibility to style the parent tag. Thanks